# Get value from Multiple table SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have three tables where as I got to consolidate and get the count.

**tbl1**

```
   ID  docID

   1      15

   2      16

   3      17
```

this will have list. there is a second table

```
tbl2
   ID - UserID- tbl1ID - ISviewed
   1  - 20    - 1      - 1
```

Table3 which has all the Users- UserID.

**tbl3**

> ```
>   UserID   - FirstName -- Last Name
>     20      -   SK       -- Kool
>     21      -  abc       -- def
> ```

I need to write a select statement where userID will be given and got to fetch the count of `tbl1` where in `tbl2`, `tbl1ID is not exist`.

for example over here the output should be **2**. Since `tbl1ID` **1** is used in `tbl2`. All these things I am getting via `PHP` controlling there in php is easy but I want to do it in `sql Select statement`

Comment: Can you put a sample row for table 3, I ma not understanding what it is you need.

Comment: edited the same with table 3

Comment: and a sample output row that you want the result of the query to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i get what do you mean is select from table 1 where id in table 1 doesn't exist on table two..

you can use this:

```
SELECT * from table1 a where a.ID NOT IN (SELECT b.tbl1ID from table2 b)
```

Comment: this doesn't do what you asked for in the question, but glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

```
select COUNT(*) from Table_1
where Table_1.ID NOT IN(SELECT Table_2.table1ID FROM Table_2)
```